# how to add notification by javascript jquery (and costum code simple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, github, toast

```js
$(".showme").click(function() {
  NToast(
    "#5060DC",     /* BACKGOUND COLOR */
    "tr",          /* TR - TOP RIGHT | TL - TOP LEFT | BR - BOTTOM RIGHT | BL - BOTTOM LEFT*/
    "Welcome To NToastJs, this is beta version ..", /* NOTIFICATION DESCRIPTION */
    true,          /* ICONS [FALSE,TRUE] */
    "fa fa-check", /* COSTUM ICONS [fontawesome or others] */
    true,           /* show hide progress bar [FALSE,TRUE] */
 "500"      /* 0.1.6v change autoclose time (if you delete line -> auto on normal speed [125]) */
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b1cd5862d8.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nShanidze/NToastJS/0.1.6v/NToast.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nShanidze/NToastJS/0.1.6v/NToast.min.js"></script>


<style>.NToastJs-progress {margin-top: 21.5px;}.NToastJs-close{margin-top: -31px;}</style>

<button class='showme'>show NToastJS Notification</button>
```

view github page https://nshanidze.github.io/NToastJS/

CDN
Toast.css - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nShanidze/NToastJS/assets/NToast.css
NToast.js - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nShanidze/NToastJS/assets/NToast.js

Toast-min.css - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nShanidze/NToastJS/assets/NToast-min.css
NToast.min.js - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nShanidze/NToastJS/assets/NToast.min.js

```
NToast(
    (1:option) => "#5060DC",                         ( background color )
    (2:option) =>  "tr",                             ( position:  TR - TopRight / TL - TopLeft | BR - BottomRight | BL - BottomLeft )
    (3:option) =>  "Welcome To NToastJs, this is beta version ..",      ( text )
    (4:option) =>  true,                             ( icon [FALSE,TRUE] )
    (5:option) =>  "fa fa-check",                    ( change icon only class name [fontawesome or others] )
    (6:option) =>  true                              ( show hide progress bar [FALSE,TRUE] )
)



NToast(

"#5060DC", 
"tr", 
"Welcome To NToastJs,
this is beta version",
true, 
"fa fa-check",
true
)
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. 
Is there a question here?

Comment: [Is it OK to promote my own code by answering my own questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255509/is-it-ok-to-promote-my-own-code-by-answering-my-own-questions)